# DownloadString Exception when installing Chocolatey on Docker Windows Container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, chocolatey, windows-container

I have been trying to install Chocolatey on a windows container and I get the below DownloadString exception.
Tried with `RUN powershell -Command [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12` to add Tls12 explicitly. Tried `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:20H2` and `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8` base images and I get the same error.

Dockerfile

```
ROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

USER ContainerAdministrator

RUN powershell -Command [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

RUN powershell -Command Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://community.chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
```

Exception I am getting -

```
Exception calling "DownloadString" with "1" argument(s): "The underlying
connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."
At line:1 char:166
 + ...  -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('ht ...
 +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
```

- Host OS - Windows 10 Enterprise x64 v10.0.19044 Build 19044
- Hyper-V Manager - v10.0.19041.1

Comment: why do you use powershell to invoke .net classes, when there are other built in powershell commdlets to download files?

Comment: I am pretty new to Docker and using powershell commands. I tried with cmd shell too but I get the same exception. Would appreciate if you know other ways to install Chocolatey on Windows container.